# yarn build do not read package from existing node_modules

Tags: node-modules

I have generated node_modules on one of my machine and copying it to other machine and running `yarn build` command their but it gives error

`code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND', requireStack: [ '/root/Sample/my-console/node_modules/.bin/ts-node' ] }`

but `ts-node` is already their in node_modules folder where yarn build command tried to see.

How can I run my code with `yarn build` I don't want to generate node_modules again.

yarn build command should read packages from node_modules and run successfully your text